# Idioms for compiler development in Clojure

Tags: compiler-construction, clojure

I'd like to explore the power of Clojure for compiler development, but I cannot find example to start with.

I am a total newbie (coming from Ruby), but I'm convinced that Clojure should be ideal for this purpose.

Let's precise what I'm looking for :

- start from a simple **AST defined in clojure** (for let say a simple sequential language : if, while, func, assign, expression)
- simple **visitor for this AST** (pretty printer for example)
- I am not really interested by lexing/parsing (as I consider s-expression as sufficient for my DSL syntax)

What are the right idioms for this in Clojure ?

Comment: You do not have to limit your search to the Clojure examples. There are many examples from the other Lisps which can easily be ported to Clojure. E.g., http://bit.ly/3t1DX or http://bit.ly/I2LFdr

Comment: I agree. This remark could also apply for Functional languages in general, but I'd like to restrict to Clojure, as it seems to be more accessible/attractive than older lisps, for non lispians. "The best lisp ever" said someone ?

Comment: no, functional languages in general is a totally different topic. Clojure is a Lisp, in a sense that it features the most important part of a Lisp - a decent macro system. And this is what actually makes Lisp different, makes it more fit for compilers development than any other language. Take a look at my second link, it employs a specialised DSL for defining visitors. This is exactly an idiomatic Lisp way of doing things. And it is the same in all the Lisps. As for "the best lisp ever" I personally would not agree. Lisp with no `cons` is not quite a Lisp. And `recur` is horrible.

Comment: P.S., you can also take a look at Racket - the whole thing is just brilliant, and it implements many various compilers inside. It is probably the single richest source of idiomatic Lisp compilers code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the simplest trivial example I can think of, using an AST tree built from s-expressions with keyword operators:

```
;; functions map, can be easily extended with new functions
;; map is of keyword -> code generating function
(def funcs {:if 
                 (fn [cond exp1 exp2] `(if ~cond ~exp1 ~exp2))
            :neg 
                 (fn [exp1] `(- 0 ~exp1))
            :plus 
                 (fn [& exps] `(+ ~@exps))})

;; compile directly to Clojure source code
(defn my-compile [code]
 (cond 
   (sequential? code)   ;; if we have a list, look up the function in funcs
     (cons (funcs (first code)) (map compile (rest code))) 
   :else                ;; treat anything else as a constant literal
     code))

;; example compilation to a Clojure expression
(my-compile `(:if true (:neg 10) (:plus 10 20 30)))
=> (if true (clojure.core/- 0 10) (clojure.core/+ 10 20 30))

;; evaluate compiled code
(eval (my-compile `(:if true (:neg 10) (:plus 10 20 30))))
=> -10
```

Hopefully that's enough to give you some ideas / get you started. Obvious extensions to consider would be:

- Compile to AST tree with metadata rather than directly to Clojure source. A Clojure `defrecord` might be suitable as an AST node representation
- Add other operators, looping constructs, "goto" etc.
- Simple optimisations, e.g. evaluation of constant expressions at compile time
- Have some form of execution context allowing assignment, dynamic variable lookup etc. The compiler output could be a function that takes the initial context as input and returns the final context.